# Element.closest() returns null on existing HTML element

Tags: javascript

For one of my study project, I have to create a cart system. On the cart.html page, the cart is supposed to be displayed. Until there, I am good.

When the user changes the quantity of one of the item, I am supposed to update it, using `Element.closest()`.

My problem is : when I change the quantity of one of the products, the console displays `null` whereas it should display the correct element.

Where is the problem coming from ?

I wrote the following code :

```
  article = document.getElementsByTagName('article'),
  quantity = document.getElementsByClassName('itemQuantity');

const cartContent = getLocalStorage('totalCart');
let i = 0,
  array = [],
  datasetArray = [];

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  cartContent.map((element) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${element.id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        displayContent(data, element);
        convertCollectionToArray(article);
        addListenerOnCollection(quantity, 'change');
      });
  });
});

/**
 * Displays elements on cart page
 * @param { Object } cart Contains fetched elements according to id stored in localStorage
 * @param { Object } storageElement Contains id, color and quantity of storaged products
 */
function displayContent(cart, storageElement) {
  cartItems.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    `<article class="cart__item" data-id="${storageElement.id}" data-color="${storageElement.color}">
      <div class="cart__item__img">
        <img src="${cart.imageUrl}" alt="Photographie d'un canapé">
      </div>
      <div class="cart__item__content">
        <div class="cart__item__content__description">
          <h2>${cart.name}</h2>
          <p>${storageElement.color}</p>
          <p>${cart.price}€</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
          <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
            <p>Qté : </p>
            <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" id="quantity" min="1" max="100" value="${storageElement.quantity}">
          </div>
          <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
            <p class="deleteItem">Supprimer</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>`
  );
}

function convertCollectionToArray(htmlCollection) {
  array = Array.from(htmlCollection);
}

function getDataset(array) {
  array.map((element) => {
    datasetArray.push(element.dataset);
  });
}

function addListenerOnCollection(collection) {
  for (var index in collection) {
    collection[index].onchange = function () {
      updateCartQuantity(article.item(index).dataset);
    };
  }
}

function updateCartQuantity(dataset) {
  let elementToUpdate = cartItems.closest(
    `.cart__item[data-id="${dataset.id}"][data-color="${dataset.color}"]`
  );
  
}

function getQuantity() {
  let newQuantity;
  for (index in quantity) {
    newQuantity = quantity.item(index).value;
  }
  return newQuantity;
}
```

Comment: Where does `cartItems` come from?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to write it in my code. It should before article, and looks like this :
`const cartItems = document.querySelector('.cart #cart__items'),`

Comment: @Programmeur77 There is no element having the id `cart__items` in the code you provided.

Comment: @Tom, thank you for your answer. The `#cart__items` element is in the HTML :
`<section id="cart__items"></section>`
This is where the code of `displayContent()` places HTML element